# Stop a promise chain without using reject in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

According to this [blog post](http://blog.zeit.io/stop-a-promise-chain-without-using-reject-with-angular-s-q/), it's possible to return `null` in a resolver function to skip over subsequent `then` handlers in a promise chain. I'm curious as to how this works -- nothing in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) defines this behavior that I can see.

For my use case, I adapted their example to handle rejections from the [`$uibModal`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) modal dialog service in Angular UI Bootstrap, which resolves or rejects depending on whether the modal is closed or dismissed:

```js
$uibModal.open({
  // ... modal options
})
.result
.catch(function () {
  // Modal dialog was dismissed, so use this trick to stop the promise chain
  return $q(function () { return null; });
})
.then(function () {
  // ... this will not get executed if dialog was dismissed
  return someAPIcall();
})
.catch(function () {
 // ... handle errors with API call
});
```

This is nice because I don't have to check the error value (the `$uibModal` API uses various strings for modal rejection types) in the first `catch` or use complex branching/nesting to avoid mixing the handling of modal dismissal rejections with errors produced by `someAPIcall()`.

But how does it work? Where is this documented?

Comment: That article is patently WRONG.  There's no `return null` to skip all `.then()` handlers in any promise specification.  Perhaps there was some non-standard implementation that did that - I have no idea. 
And, the article explicitly says that it doesn't work in angular.  You either reject or you return a specific value that subsequent `.then()` handlers check for.  That's how you control what executes next with promises.

Comment: The blog post is wrong. Test it by yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/yc2jygfc/.

Comment: FYI, you can return `null` when the dialog is dismissed and then just check to see if value is `null` in the next `.then()` handler and if so, don't execute the API call.  That's how you'd do it in synchronous code (with an `if` statement), same concept in async code.

Comment: This fiddle works in AngularJS, still unsure why: https://jsfiddle.net/8o5tLac3/

Comment: So I think I understand what's going on, the usage of the $q constructor in the blog as well as my example is wrong and not doing what I thought, rather it is returning a promise that will never reject or resolve (forever in the `pending` state). So the side effect was the behavior I was seeing but not working how I thought.